# How to open a Web Page with JavaScript inserted

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

I want to create a new window with JavaScript Inserted, for example:

Open Google with `window.open` **but** I have the JavaScript `alert();` inserted into it.

When Searching, I found you can use `window.open` to open a actualy window and [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_openallwindow)

which allows you to create a new window with custom options
(`window.open("https://www.w3schools.com","_blank","toolbar=yes, location=yes, directories=no, status=no, menubar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=yes, width=400, height=400");`)

So is there any way to insert JavaScript like this?

**ALSO**
*if you are confused*

Here is a basic description.
I want to open `google.com` with the JavaScript tag `alert();` inserted with the `window.open` in JavaScript.

( I am also using plain JavaScript, nothing like `node.js`)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inject code into another website, no.

Comment: I thought you could because [GoGaurdian](https://gogaurdian.com) is a program at my school we use, and it uses JavaScript/JSON (_i think?_)  with a tag like `window.location.replace();`  So I thought I could use this. Also I am using this in a chrome extension, that runs in the background, so is this still not possible?

Comment: Ah yes with an extension you could show alerts

Comment: and how would I do that? as the `<script>` HTML tag does not work in chrome extensions

Comment: if you can i would gladly accept other questions

Comment: I would just google how to write a Chrome extension. You can include scripts throughout your extension.